# Close Event are not called Keyboard Event and MessageBox

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer, qdialog

I programming with QT Designer a GUI and would like disable the Close Event with ESC-Key. The User has the possibility to close the Application with X on the top but not with any Keys.

The Function **closeEvent(self,event)** are not working.

```
def closeEvent(self, event):
    close = QMessageBox()
    close.setText("You sure?")
    close.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.Cancel)
    close = close.exec()

    if close == QMessageBox.Yes:
        event.accept()
    else:
        event.ignore()
```

The function are on my main class: **class Ui_Tool(object)**

```
class Ui_LabelTool(object):
def setupUi(self, LabelTool):
    Tool.setObjectName("Tool")
    Tool.resize(650, 569)
    Tool.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(650, 569))
    Tool.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(650, 569))
    Tool.setAutoFillBackground(False)
    Tool.setSizeGripEnabled(False)
    ...

    #Events for Buttons
    self.SelectFolder.clicked.connect(self.setfolder)   
    self.SelectOutputFolder.clicked.connect(self.SetOutputFolder)       
    self.LoadeMeasurement.clicked.connect(self.LoadRecording)           
    self.StartButton.clicked.connect(self.startProcessing)              
    self.Next_btn.clicked.connect(self.nextOperation)                   
    self.Prev_Btn.clicked.connect(self.prefOperation)                   
    self.Reset_btn.clicked.connect(self.resetApp)

    self.treeView.clicked.connect(self.ClickMeasurement) 
    self.treeWidget.clicked.connect(self.CheckTopicSelect)              

    self.horizontalSlider.valueChanged.connect(self.SliderValueChange)
    self.horizontalSlider.sliderMoved.connect(self.dispSlider)

    self.BBObject_btn.clicked.connect(self.CreateBBObj)
    self.BBNoObject_btn.clicked.connect(self.CreateBBNoObj)

    self.ShowAll_btn.clicked.connect(self.SaveImages)

def retranslateUi(self, LabelTool):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    Tool.setWindowTitle(_translate("Tool", "Tool"))
    self.LoadeMeasurement.setText(_translate("Tool", "Load Measurement"))
    self.StartButton.setText(_translate("Tool", "Start "))
    self.Reset_btn.setText(_translate("Tool", "Reset"))
    self.Header_lbl.setText(_translate("Tool", "Test"))
    ...
```

And this is my main Function:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Tool = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Tool()
    ui.setupUi(Tool)
    Tool.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

What I do wrong?

I add the following class:

```
class Logic(QMainWindow, Ui_Tool):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    QMainWindow.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    self.setupUi(self)

def closeEvent(self, event):
    answer = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.question(
        self,
        'Are you sure you want to quit ?',
        'Task is in progress !',
        QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes,
        QtWidgets.QMessageBox.No)
    if answer == QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes:
        event.accept()
    else:
        event.ignore()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But the implementation of Logic class not works. Must I change anything on the main Function??

Comment: you mean in the class Logic?? I do this, but not works.. I read youur explanation

Comment: if __name__ ==" __main __ ": No, i change there notthing. This was my question, if change there anything?

Comment: app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
     LabelTool = QtWidgets.QDialog()
     ui = Ui_LabelTool()
     ui.setupUi(LabelTool)
    #LabelTool.show()
    w = Logic()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_()) But not works..

Comment: Then I became a Error: name 'Tool' is not defined: In **class UI_Tool* in **function __init__** self.setupUi(LabelTool)

Comment: I share the class on the description of my question..

Comment: I add the constructor, because I saw this in a forum. I delete this and the code are running. But the close event are not work.. I add my class on description

Comment: I have the same Code as the cde in the link. But If i clicked the ESC Key my Gui are close without any MessageBox

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question, do you want that when the user presses the escape key then closeEvent is invoked?

Comment: Yess, I saw that the Code from you works only, if I clicked the X on the top.. But I want to do this with ESC Key..

Comment: see my answer--

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#escape-key) is reviewed:

> #### Escape Key
>
> If the user presses the Esc key in a dialog, QDialog::reject() will be
>   called. This will cause the window to close: The close event cannot be
>   ignored.

So there are 2 possible solutions:

1. Override keyPressEvent() method, when you press the <kbd>escape</kbd> key, call close().
2. Override reject() method to make the verification of the QMessageBox and according to it make its logic.

In addition to this implementation you must do it in the widget and not in the class generated by Qt Designer<sup>(1)</sup>, considering the above the implementations of both solutions are:

1.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_LabelTool(object):
    def setupUi(self, Tool):
        Tool.setObjectName("Tool")
        Tool.resize(650, 569)
        Tool.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(650, 569))
        Tool.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(650, 569))
        Tool.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        Tool.setSizeGripEnabled(False)
        # ....


class LabelTool(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_LabelTool):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(LabelTool, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

    def verify_by_user(self):
        answer = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.question(
            self,
            "Are you sure you want to quit ?",
            "Task is in progress !",
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes,
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.No,
        )
        return answer == QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Escape:
            self.close()
        else:
            super(LabelTool, self).keyPressEvent(event)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        if self.verify_by_user():
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = LabelTool()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

2.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_LabelTool(object):
    def setupUi(self, Tool):
        Tool.setObjectName("Tool")
        Tool.resize(650, 569)
        Tool.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(650, 569))
        Tool.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(650, 569))
        Tool.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        Tool.setSizeGripEnabled(False)
        # ....


class LabelTool(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_LabelTool):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(LabelTool, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

    def verify_by_user(self):
        answer = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.question(
            self,
            "Are you sure you want to quit ?",
            "Task is in progress !",
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes,
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.No,
        )
        return answer == QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes

    def reject(self):
        if self.verify_by_user():
            super(LabelTool, self).reject()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        if self.verify_by_user():
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = LabelTool()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

<sup>(1) [Using the Generated Code](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html#using-the-generated-code)</sup>